# SQL cte delete operation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a cte that loops through the records creates a list and I pass a parameter of `@ParamterID` in a select statement but the set operations says incorrect syntax near Set and in that select it gets the path where I can do a search for the paths that are LIKE '%' + @Path + '%' and those are the items I want to delete from the table called Post. could someone help me complete this please and correct my SET @Path syntax

```
DELCARE @ParmeterID int = 3
DECLARE @Path nvarchar(MAX) 

WITH cte(Url, Level, Path, PostID, ParentPostID)
AS (

SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(Title), ' ', '-'), 1 AS Level, CAST(PostID as nvarchar(MAX)) as Path,
PostID, ParentPostID
FROM Post
WHERE ParentPostID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT cte.Url, cte.Level + 1,
LOWER(cte.Path + '-' +  CAST(P.PostID AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
P.PostID,  P.ParentPostID 
FROM Post P 
INNER JOIN cte ON P.ParentPostID = cte.PostID
)
-- says incorrect sybnatx near Set @Path
SET @Path = (SELECT Path FROM cte WHERE PostID = @ParemeterID); 


-- list i want to delete --
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE Path LIKE '%' + @Path + '%'

delete -- list -- FROM Post --
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do (I don't know your table schema) but you can try this:

```
DECLARE @ParmeterID int = 3

WITH cte(Url, Level, Path, PostID, ParentPostID)
AS (
    SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(Title), ' ', '-'), 1 AS Level, CAST(PostID as nvarchar(MAX)) as Path,
    PostID, ParentPostID
    FROM Post
    WHERE ParentPostID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.Url, cte.Level + 1,
    LOWER(cte.Path + '-' +  CAST(P.PostID AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
    P.PostID,  P.ParentPostID 
    FROM Post P 
    INNER JOIN cte ON P.ParentPostID = cte.PostID
)

delete p
from post p
join cte on p.postId = cte.postId and 
    cte.path like '%' + (select top 1 [path] from cte where postId = @ParmeterID) + '%'
```

**Addedd**: Ordering by `path`, please mind that this is a quick and dirty way.

```
WITH cte(Url, Level, Path, PostID, ParentPostID, Sequence)
AS (
    SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(Title), ' ', '-'), 1 AS Level, CAST(PostID as nvarchar(MAX)) as Path,
    PostID, ParentPostID, right(replicate('0', 8) + cast(PostID as varchar(max)), 8)
    FROM Post
    WHERE ParentPostID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.Url, cte.Level + 1,
    LOWER(cte.Path + '-' +  CAST(P.PostID AS VARCHAR(MAX))),
    P.PostID,  P.ParentPostID, cte.sequence + right(replicate('0', 8) + cast(p.PostID as varchar(max)), 8)
    FROM Post P 
    INNER JOIN cte ON P.ParentPostID = cte.PostID
)
select Url, Level, Path, PostID, ParentPostID
from cte
order by Sequence
```

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks very much that helps heaps. You're onto it dude

Comment: If i wanted todo a Count of posts I could just do a select COUNT(*) From Posts WHERE Url = 'whatever' at the end of my cte will that work it should do

Comment: To count posts use `select count(*) from cte where url= 'whatever'` just after the `cte`.

Comment: I have another question? Remove the delete statement after the cte When I do a select statement on my cte I might have records that go something like this in my Path 1-2-1-1 then 1-2-1-5 then 1-2-1-10 where the third one will be hihger than the second when you do sort by Path. Do you know how todo a select statement that can handle the superior order properly can you help on that please

Comment: That worked thankyou. I've posted another question you might be able to answer for me could you check it out please heres the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997249/second-insert-statement-build-a-path